# How to fetch data from database according to date using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT *
FROM `reg`
WHERE registration_date
BETWEEN '29 /01 /15'
AND '30 /01 /15'
```

I am using this query to fetch data from the database, it gives me the data, but when I  *change* the date, for example `BETWEEN '29/01/15' AND '06/03/15'`, it show *nothing*.
I am using the datatype `varchar`.

Can anyone help me solve this error?

Comment: show here how did you store the date in table

Comment: Either use a date data type for storing dates or don't bother with an RDBMS

Answer (score 2):

From the **MySQL manual**: 
The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. 
*MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format*. 
The **supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'**.

You **need to change** the **format** you use for the dates.

Try

```
SELECT * FROM reg WHERE registration_date BETWEEN '2015-01-29' AND '2015-01-30'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use WHERE condition as below as in table date is saved in "Y-m-d" format :

```
WHERE registration_date BETWEEN '2015-01-29' AND '2015-01-30'
```

Comment: i used this but this condition works in date datatype , i am using varchar datatype

Comment: Did u check that the stored data is in which format?. For ex. it may be in this format '2015-11-18 11:26:13' or it can be in simple format without time '2015-11-18'. so the query may affect the results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for you, I have also use these method to get data using date, Please try it mayhelp you :-

```
$start  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('29-01-2015'));
$end    = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('30-01-2015'));

SELECT *
FROM `reg`
WHERE registration_date >= $start AND 
registration_date <= $end;
```

Comment: Yeah, but you're comparing by string hexcode, with year in the front, then month then day, which is good, but his database is storing the date as day, then month then year so the hexcode comparison will fail. You need to convert his date string in the table to use year/month/day before you can use it with the hexcode trick with between/and if it's going to do so *correctly*. My solution is better in that it uses solid logic.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are using data type `Varchar` so it will between and And will not work. it is showing your result because it comparing to binary digit .so it is showing you result between the two binary digits. You need to change your data type to Date and Time.

Answer (score 0):

Your query only works because BETWEEN/AND in your case is only checking that the hexcode of the characters used in the string are between each other. You will also get a result for:

```
SELECT * FROM `reg` WHERE registration_date BETWEEN '29/dur' AND '30/3.13159'
```

But if you'd like to treat your query like actual dates, I'd suggest using:

```
SELECT * FROM `reg`
WHERE str_to_date(registration_date,'%d/%m/%Y')
BETWEEN
str_to_date('29/01/15','%d/%m/%Y') AND str_to_date('30/01/15','%d/%m/%Y')
```